# Classic ASP emails not working with Outlook SMTP relay

Tags: email, asp-classic, smtp, office365

I am trying to get the classic ASP page working with Outlook (Microsoft Web Email) SMTP  relay. I am getting the following error :

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'
The transport failed to connect to the server.
```

My code looks like

```
dim objEmail                
Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("cdo.message") 
objEmail.To = list
objEmail.From = "xyz@abc.com"  
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpServer
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = username
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = password
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
```

I tested with GMAIL and this thing snippet works fine with it. I guess I am missing something in configuration of Outlook SMTP

Comment: Can you enable verbose logging of this "cdo" mailer and look at the detailed conversation with the server? GMAIL most likely won't be 100% compatible with microsoft's implementation/settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that does work. Make sure that the account you use has a mailbox, and the from adress is indeed the account adress.

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        var msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Subject = "Hello";
        msg.Body = "Hello Sir";
        msg.From = new MailAddress("no.reply@contoso.com");
        msg.To.Add("user@contoso.com");

        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.office365.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("no.reply@contoso.com", "******");
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: I know it works fine in ASP.NET, but I am talking about classic ASP.